# can i see lotus notes hidden-document with reader field

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

in this document, I use reader field to set who can read this document but as first my program is fault that wrong people set in this field and nobody can read this document. I write a code to see all document and that hidden document not show any item.

```
Set db=session.currentdatabase
Set dc=db.alldocuments
Dim i_count As Integer
For i_count = 1 To dc.Count 
    Set doccoll = dc.GetNthDocument(i_count)
Next
```

This is the result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyyu6.jpg)

How can I change reader field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enable "Full Access Administration" on administrator client to see all documents in that server.